# for which $n$ does $\int_0^1 sin(x)^n|ln(x)|^2dx$ converges?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I wonder for which real number $n$ the integral $\int_0^1 sin(x)^n|ln(x)|^2dx$ converges. If $n\geq 0$ i think the answer is yes, since $|sin(x)^n|ln(x)|^2|\leq |ln(x)|^2$ and $\int_0^1 |ln(x)|^2dx$ converges. I'm however clueless when $n$ is non-positive.

Comment: Would it help if you used $x/2 \le \sin x\le x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since over $[0,1]$ we have $x\geq \sin x \geq \sin(1)\, x$, when $n<0$ we have:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sin^n(x) \log^2(x)\,dx \geq \int_{0}^{1} x^n\log^2(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}y^2 e^{-(n+1)y}\,dy. $$
If $n\leq -1$ the last integral is obviously divergent. In the other case, $n>-1$, we have:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sin^n(x) \log^2(x)\,dx \leq \sin(1)^n\int_{0}^{+\infty}y^2 e^{-(n+1)y}\,dy = \sin(1)^n\cdot\frac{2}{(n+1)^3}, $$
hence the integral is convergent.

Comment: i didnt point out that n is a real number here. This works indeed if n is at most -1, but what happens i -1<n<0 ?I corrected the question.

Comment: ok so it seems that the integral converges for $-1<n$ by a slight modification. Is it ok?

Comment: @LouisLaBrocante: yes, you are right, I have just updated my answer.